# Rails add text to class in a content_tag_for :li

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a content tag that is creating jquery sortable output.
Some items I don't want sortable, so I've added the following to the jquery:

```
    cancel: ".ui-state-disabled"
```

So, now I need to put "ui-state-disabled" into the li class.

Currently the code creating the li is this:

```
               <% wostatus.workorders.each do |workorder| %>
                <%= content_tag_for(:li, workorder) do %>
                    <div class="<%= workorder.type.maximo_no %> <%= workorder.priority %> ">
                      <a href="<%= workorder_path(workorder) %>">
                        <strong><%= workorder.wonum %></strong>
                        <%= workorder.description %>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
```

The results in HTML are:

```
<li class="workorder" id="workorder_36">
    <div class="  ">
       <a href="/workorders/36">
          <strong>13-39870</strong>
                        Added some text again
          </a>
    </div>
</li>
```

In the browser, if I edit the li class to include "ui-state-disabled" it works the way I want.

Now, how can I insert the "ui-state-disabled" into the li status if the workorder.wostatus.id = 232 ??

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a helper:

```
def disabled_workorder_li(workorder)
  {:class => "ui-state-disabled"} if workorder.id == 232
end
```

Then in the view:

```
<%= content_tag_for(:li, workorder, disabled_workorder_li(workorder) %>
```

Here's what it would look like if you skipped the helper and tried to do it all in the view:

```
<%= content_tag_for(:li, workorder, 
(workorder.id == 232) ? {:class => "ui_state_disabled"} : nil %>
```

That looks terrible.  Putting it into a helper will also make it easier to test.

Comment: I've never made a helper before - where does it go? In the model? Thanks!

Comment: They go in app/helpers, you can put in in the application_helper.rb or create a new one.